# how do I animate a nested element with jquery?

Tags: jquery, animation, selector

how do I animate a nested element with jquery?  I've been trying to make a table visible using jquery for hours and it won't work. the commented out

```
//document.getElementById("passwordCon").style.visibility="visible";
```

works just fine but I want to animate it. What is wrong!!! I tried to use the animate function and visibility:visible but nothing will work. The id is in reference to a table id.

Edit: The html style attribute for the table is visibility:hidden. I want to show the table via jquery and animation.

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#username").keyup(function(){
        $.post("tryUser.php",
        {
           name:$(this).serialize()
        },
        function(data){
            if(data == "no")
            {   
                //document.getElementById("passwordCon").style.visibility="visible";
                $("#passwordCon").fadeIn(500);
            }
            else 
            {                    
                document.getElementById("passwordConfTitle").style.visibility="hidden";
                document.getElementById("passwordCon").style.visibility="hidden";
            }
        });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("#passwordCon").hide().fadeIn(500);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, it's hidden by default.

Comment: How is it hidden? in case it's visibility: hidden

@Arun P Johny is correct and you have to use his answer. or remove the visibility property and use mine.

Comment: I made it hidden. I don't want "confirm password" to appear unless the username doesn't match any users in my database. Hence the need to make it visible.

Comment: Is there no way to animate visibility directly?

Answer (score 0):

Try using hide:

```
  $("#passwordCon").hide(1000);
```

You can check for sample codes:

http://w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_slow

http://w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think `fadeIn` is not supported by `visibility: hidden`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3xEVZ/1/)

One possible workaround is to use opacity

```
$('#test').css({opacity: 0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 500)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3xEVZ/2/)